# Could anyone explain how is this Matlab code for log likelihood of Gaussian distribution implemented?

Tags: algorithms, matlab

I was implementing Expectation-maximization algorithm for gaussian mixture module. However I realized my implementation has very bad accuracy. Then I found some code on internet.

It seems this function calculates the log likelihood of multi-variant Gaussian distribution, which should be defined as:

$$\ln(L) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln (|\boldsymbol\Sigma|\,) -\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{z}-\boldsymbol\mu)^\dagger\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{z}-\boldsymbol\mu) - \frac{k}{2}\ln(2\pi)$$

where $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ is covariance matrix and $\mathbf{z}$ is data points, $\boldsymbol\mu$ is mean and k is the dimension of the data.

But the author $\textit{Michael Chen}$ implemented the code as follows.

```
function y = loggausspdf(X, mu, Sigma)
    d = size(X,1);
    X = bsxfun(@minus,X,mu);
    [U,p]= chol(Sigma);
    if p ~= 0
        error('ERROR: Sigma is not PD.');
    end
    Q = U'\X;
    q = dot(Q,Q,1);  % quadratic term (M distance)
    c = d*log(2*pi)+2*sum(log(diag(U)));   % normalization constant
    y = -(c+q)/2;
end
```

Can anyone explain how is this function implemented.

thx !

Comment: What in particular are you having trouble with? It is exactly an implementation of the equation you posted.

Comment: How is Cholesky factorization related to the problem. I don't understand Q = U'\X; and q = dot(Q,Q,1);

Comment: Posting an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $\Sigma$ is positive definite, so it can be written in terms of a lower triangular matrix and its (conjugate) transpose using Cholesky factorization:

$$\Sigma = L L^{*},$$

or alternatively an upper triangular matrix:

$$\Sigma = U^{*} U.$$

This can be inverted: $\Sigma^{-1} = (U^*U)^{-1} = U^{-1}U^{-*}$.

Now, our inner term looks like

$$x^*\Sigma^{-1}x = x^*U^{-1}U^{-*}x.$$

Note that $U^{-*}x$ is the solution to the equation $U^*v = x$. In MATLAB, we can solve such a linear equation using the backslash command as `U'\X`.

Finally, noting that $x^*U^{-1}U^{-*}x$ is symmetric, and that they are vectors, we essentially have

$$\underbrace{x^*U^{-1}}_{v^*}\underbrace{U^{-*}x}_{v} = v^* v = v\cdot v.$$

Comment: The code you found scores good marks for efficiency and equally poor marks for documentation. These are precisely the things that should be documented in numerical code.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very good explanation !

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For any symmetric positive-definite matrix $\Sigma$ the Cholesky decomposition is given by $\Sigma = U U^t$ where $U$ is triangular; this can be efficiently computed. Now, $x^t \Sigma^{-1} x = x^t {(U^{-1})}^{t} {U^{-1}} x = y^t y $ where $y=U^{-1} x$. This is what the code is computing.

Comment: Thanks! I also think it is much faster than my code. However I think the time complexity for inverting a matrix and Cholesky decomposition are all $O(n^3)$, right ?

Comment: I think the advantage goes more for the numerical stability than speed, but there's a lot of factors here. See eg http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3188/dealing-with-the-inverse-of-a-positive-definite-symmetric-covariance-matrix

Comment: thanks a lot! It seems this technique is common in computational science.